# How to create a set number of folders accepting user input in PowerShell Plus

Tags: powershell, foreach, directory

I am attempting to create 12 folders one for each month by prompting the user to enter the year. Once the user enters the year I have the program check if the folder name is existing. If it does not exist I want the program to create the folder name with _01, _02, _03, etc... at the end of the folder name automatically producing the folder name example 2020_01. I can create a single folder without the foreach statement. Once I add the foreach to limit the number of folders and automatically name the folder I am unsuccessful. Any guidance would be appreciated.

```
$folderpath = "C:\MyScripts"
Do
    {
        $curryear = Join-Path $folderpath (Read-Host -Prompt "Enter the year
        for the folder structure: ")
        If (Test-Path -Path $curryear)
        {
            $existingFolder = $true
            Write-Host "Folder exists"
        }
        Else
        {
            $existingFolder = $false
            ForEach-Object {
            New-Item -Path $folderpath -ItemType Directory -Name ($curryear + "-01") |
            Out-Null
            Write-Host "Creating folder name " $curryear
            }
        }
    }  While ($existingFolder)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your for-each loop, you are not defining any numbers or list to go over. You need to define the numbers, such as 1 - 12 (for the months) to iterate over and create the folders based on these numbers. I used `(1..12)` which is about the same as using for loop, `for (int i = 0; i< 12; i++)`.

Also, while you are iterating over these numbers, you can use formatting option to use 01 instead of just 1 when creating the folders for consistency in names. For that, use -f option `("0:d2" -f 1)`. [Find details on formatting here](https://ss64.com/ps/syntax-f-operator.html)

Another issue i noticed was that you were using full path as name of the folder, when creating the folder. You only need to provide the name in `-Name` parameter since you are providing the `Path` already. Changed `$curryear` assignment for that.

```
$folderpath = "C:\Temp\Date"
Do
{
    $curryear = Read-Host -Prompt "Enter the year for the folder structure: "
    If (Test-Path -Path (Join-Path $folderpath $curryear*))
    {
        $existingFolder = $true
        Write-Host "Folder exists"
    }
    Else
    {
        $existingFolder = $false
        (1..12) | ForEach-Object {
            $month = curryear + ("_{0:d2}" -f $_)
            New-Item -Path $folderpath -ItemType Directory -Name $month |Out-Null
            Write-Host "Creating folder name " $month
        }
    }
}  While ($existingFolder)
```

Another variation to the above is to continue creating folders unless you write quit. If a subfolder of a year, that already has been created before, was deleted, this process will work and create only missing folders as well.

```
$folderpath = "C:\Temp\Date"
While ($true)
{
    $curryear = Read-Host -Prompt "Enter the year for the folder structure (quit): "
    if ($curryear -eq "quit") {
       break
    }

    (1..12) | ForEach-Object {
        $month = $curryear + ("_{0:d2}" -f $_)
        try {
            New-Item -Path $folderpath -ItemType Directory -Name $month -ea Stop |Out-Null
            Write-Host "Creating folder name " $month
        }
        catch{
            Write-Host "Folder $month already exists"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: How can you echo the folder name created?

Comment: @CVYCCVYC Added * to the Test-Path statement. Also, changed the Name and Write-Host statement to use the variable $month. See changes above :)

Comment: I appreciate all your help.

Comment: @CVYCCVYC different way of creating folders (suppose a folder for specific month of a year was deleted) while continuing to loop until you write `quit`.